# POSTFIX fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtp-auth, saslauthd

I am struggling with the error above for more than 5 hours.
I had tried to remove Postfix completely and I had followed the instructions of the [next manual](https://wiki.debian.org/Postfix) and the [SASL manual](https://wiki.debian.org/PostfixAndSASL) in order to reinstall it.

When I am trying to login with telnet, the server blocks the login and I am getting this:(with smtpd -v for more verbose):

```
postfix/smtpd[26301]: xsasl_cyrus_server_create: SASL service=smtp, realm=(null)  
postfix/smtpd[26301]: name_mask: noanonymous  
postfix/smtpd[26301]: warning:   xsasl_cyrus_server_get_mechanism_list: no applicable SASL mechanisms  
postfix/smtpd[26301]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

here are the results of `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = theflipapp.com, localhost.com, , localhost
myhostname = theflipapp.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

postfix master config:

```
root@domain:/# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf | grep ^smtp
smtp    inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
```

Hopes this data will help you to help me..

Comment: For my case, on **Ubuntu Server 16.04**, dovecot daemon was not running, typing dovecot did the trick. However, this highlights an underlying issue that it's not running in bootup. You may read how to add it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto

Comment: Does `dovecot` need `cyrus` for SASL???

Answer (score 40):

You can have saslauthd installed but not have any mechanisms installed.  It's quite frustrating and poor error-proofing, IMO.

"no applicable SASL mechanisms" literally means it can't find any of its mechanisms.  On a Fedora-based system you'd need to install the cyrus-sasl-plain package if you want to use the 'PLAIN' auth mechanisms (i.e. SMTP/STARTTLS).

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain
```

or

```
apt-get install libsasl2-modules
```

Comment: Many thanks! It's really hard to find the cause of such issues and the messages in the logs don't help - only as keywords in search to find such awesome answers. You saved my day.

Comment: After `apt install libsasl2-dev` it worked on my machine.

Comment: It is worth noting that Dovecot also provides a SASL daemon usable to Postfix.

Answer (score 7):

the solution was very simple, the SASL daemon was down.
`/etc/init.d/saslauthd start`

Some hacker managed to shut it down again and again so eventually I had closed it completely.

Answer (score 5):

At first, try to change the delimiters of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to commas. Spaces are, if I remember correctly, incorrect here.

Then try to temporarily disable `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous`.

Are you trying to authenticate against a CYRUS IMAP server?

Comment: According to the main.cf man page https://linux.die.net/man/5/main.cf under smtpd_recipient_restrictions it sais: 'Specify a list of restrictions, separated by commas and/or whitespace.' So just whitespaces as a separator is just fine.