# Can't telnet to Postfix SMTP server after adding smtpd_sasl_auth_enable option

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl, smtp-auth, saslauthd

I have the Postfix SMTP server installed on my CentOS 7 machine on port 25.
To test that it's working, I connect to it using telnet, like this:

`# telnet localhost 25`

and the result is:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.app ESMTP Postfix
EHLO test.com
250-example.app
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Which means it's working fine.
But now, in Postfix's config file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I add the line:

`smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes`

Then I `postfix reload` and try the telnet connection again. And the result is:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The connection is closed automatically without receiving the 220 banner line.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I've read the entire [SASL README](http://pagehttp://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) page at postfix.org and it says nothing about `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable` having this effect.

Why is telnet unable to establish a connection in this case and how can it be solved?

Comment: Please add your complete `main.conf`. It's not the `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` itself,  but it enables the functionality, causing some other parameter to cause the problem.

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem so I guess I'll answer my own question.

The SASL library was missing the component `cyrus-sasl-plain`.

I installed it with
`yum install cyrus-sasl-plain` and problem solved.

More info in this other question: [POSTFIX fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms](https://serverfault.com/questions/571191/postfix-fatal-no-sasl-authentication-mechanisms)